# Specific SQL sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 4 relevant columns.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|USERNAME|POINTS1|POINTS2|POINTS3|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|Meredith|10     |15     |18     |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|User2   |13     |12     |11     |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|User3   |10     |3      |4      |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|Meredith|4      |9      |17     |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'd like to sort by the total number of points, so that I'd get a result like this:

```
+--------+-----+
|USERNAME|TOTAL|
+--------+-----+
|Meredith|73   |
+--------+-----+
|User2   |36   |
+--------+-----+
|User3   |17   |
+--------+-----+
```

Right now, I'm using `SELECT username, (points1 + points2 + points3) FROM table_name ORDER BY (points1 + points2 + points3) DESC LIMIT 0, 10`, which gives a result like this:

```
+--------+-----+
|USERNAME|TOTAL|
+--------+-----+
|Meredith|43   |
+--------+-----+
|User2   |36   |
+--------+-----+
|Meredith|30   |
+--------+-----+
|User3   |17   |
+--------+-----+
```

I'm not sure how to combine multiple results. It is not an option to combine both rows into a single row.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
SELECT username, sum(points1 + points2 + points3) points 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - it's better to say `sum(points1)+sum(points2)+sum(point3) as points` rather than the expression you've got`sum(points1+points2+points3)`. The difference is that for `sum(a+b+c)`, any row having a `null` for `a`, `b` will be completely excluded from the `sum()` aggregate function, since the result of any expression involving null is...null. `sum(a)+sum(b)+sum(c)` will only exclude the actual null values.